# What constitutes a fold for types other than list?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, terminology, fold

Consider a single-linked list. It looks something like

```
data List x = Node x (List x) | End
```

It is natural to define a folding function such as

```
reduce :: (x -> y -> y) -> y -> List x -> y
```

In a sense, `reduce f x0` replaces every `Node` with `f` and every `End` with `x0`. This is what the Prelude refers to as a *fold*.

Now consider a simple binary tree:

```
data Tree x = Leaf x | Branch (Tree x) (Tree x)
```

It is similarly natural to define a function such as

```
reduce :: (y -> y -> y) -> (x -> y) -> Tree x -> y
```

Notice that *this* reduction has a quite different character; whereas the list-based one is inherently sequential, this new tree-based one has more of a divide-and-conquer feel to it. You could even imagine throwing a few `par` combinators in there. (Where would you put such a thing in the list version?)

My question: Is this function still classified as a "fold", or is it something else? (And if so, what is it?)

Basically whenever anybody talks about folding, they always talk about folding *lists*, which is inherently sequential. I'm wondering whether "sequential" is part of the definition of what a fold is, or whether this is merely a coincidental property of the most commonly-used example of folding.

Comment: The order of the fold seems important enough a consideration (Inorder, preorder, post order) that I'd say the two are different. But then only if order is important to the operation itself.

Comment: You might be interested in http://vimeo.com/6624203 by Guy Steele about organising code for parallel execution (covers folds, trees and lists)

Comment: Folds are [catamorphisms](http://eprints.eemcs.utwente.nl/7281/01/db-utwente-40501F46.pdf) and their shape depends on the shapes of the data constructors for the type in question.

Comment: There's a really nice discussion of this in one of my favorite papers, *[Functional Programming with Overloading and Higher-Order Polymorphism](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/springschool.html)*, by Mark P. Jones.

Comment: @GeneralBecos - +1, but then the same applies for lists - if the operator isn't associative, `foldl` and `foldr` give different results. There's just more orders implied by the structure for trees.

Comment: Wikipedia has also a nice introduction to [catamorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism).

Comment: I uploaded a [catamorphism package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/catamorphism) which automatically generates folds for some given data type.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Tikhon's got the technical stuff down.  I think I'll try to simplify down from what he said.

The term "folding" has, unfortunately, become ambiguous over the years to mean one of two things:

1. Reducing a collection sequentially in some order.  In Haskell, this is what "folding" means in the `Foldable` class, which larsmans brings up.
2. The notion you asked for: "destructing" (opposite of *constructing*), "observing" or "eliminating" an algebraic data type according to its structure.  Also called a *catamorphism*.

It is possible to define both of these notions generically so that one parametrized function is capable of doing it for a variety of types.  Tikhon shows how to do in the second case.

But most often going the whole way with `Fix` and the algebras and such is overkill.  Let's work out a simpler way of writing the fold for any algebraic data type.  We'll use `Maybe`, pairs, lists and trees as our examples:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
data Pair a b = Pair a b
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
data Tree x = Leaf x | Branch (Tree x) (Tree x)
data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
```

Note that `Pair` is not recursive; the procedure I'm going to show doesn't assume that the "fold" type is recursive.  People don't usually call this case a "fold," but it's really the non-recursive case of the same concept.

First step: the fold for a given type will consume the folded type and produce some parameter type as its result.  I like to call the latter `r` (for "result").  So:

```
foldMaybe :: ... -> Maybe a -> r
foldPair  :: ... -> Pair a b -> r
foldList  :: ... -> List a -> r
foldTree  :: ... -> Tree a -> r
foldBTree :: ... -> BTree a -> r
```

Second step: in addition to the last argument (the one for the structure), the fold takes as many arguments as the type has constructors.  `Pair` has one constructor and our other examples have two, so:

```
foldMaybe :: nothing -> just -> Maybe a -> r
foldPair  :: pair -> Pair a b -> r 
foldList  :: nil -> cons -> List a -> r
foldTree  :: leaf -> branch -> Tree a -> r
foldBTree :: empty -> node -> BTree a -> r
```

Third step: each of these arguments has the same arity as the constructor it corresponds to.  Let's treat the constructors as functions, and write out their types (making sure the type variables match up with the ones in the signatures we're writing):

```
Nothing :: Maybe a
Just    :: a -> Maybe a

Pair    :: a -> b -> Pair a b

Nil     :: List a
Cons    :: a -> List a -> List a

Leaf    :: a -> Tree a
Branch  :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree a

Empty   :: BTree a
Node    :: a -> BTree a -> BTree a -> BTree a
```

Step 4: in the signature of each constructor, we will replace all occurrences of the data type it constructs with our type variable `r` (that we're using in our fold signatures):

```
nothing := r
just    := a -> r

pair    := a -> b -> r

nil     := r
cons    := a -> r -> r

leaf    := a -> r
branch  := r -> r -> r

empty   := r
node    := a -> r -> r -> r
```

As you can see, I've "assigned" the resulting signatures to my dummy type variables from the second step.  Now Step 5: fill those in into the earlier sketch fold signatures:

```
foldMaybe :: r -> (a -> r) -> Maybe a -> r
foldPair  :: (a -> b -> r) -> Pair a b -> r 
foldList  :: r -> (a -> r -> r) -> List a -> r
foldTree  :: (a -> r) -> (r -> r -> r) -> Tree a -> r
foldBTree :: r -> (a -> r -> r -> r) -> BTree a -> r
```

Now, these are signatures for the folds of those types.  They have a funny argument order, because I did this mechanically by reading the fold type off the `data` declarations and constructor types, but for some reason in functional programming it's conventional to put base cases first in `data` definitions yet recursive case handlers first in `fold` definitions.  No problem!  Let's reshuffle them to make them more conventional:

```
foldMaybe :: (a -> r) -> r -> Maybe a -> r
foldPair  :: (a -> b -> r) -> Pair a b -> r 
foldList  :: (a -> r -> r) -> r -> List a -> r
foldTree  :: (r -> r -> r) -> (a -> r) -> Tree a -> r
foldBTree :: (a -> r -> r -> r) -> r -> BTree a -> r
```

---

The definitions can also be filled in mechanically.  Let's pick `foldBTree` and implement it step by step.  The fold for a given type is the one function of the type we figured out that meets this condition: folding with the type's constructors is an identity function over that type (you get the same result as the value you started with).

We'll start like this:

```
foldBTree :: (a -> r -> r -> r) -> r -> BTree a -> r
foldBTree = ???
```

We know it takes three arguments, so we can add variables to reflect them.  I'll use long descriptive names:

```
foldBTree :: (a -> r -> r -> r) -> r -> BTree a -> r
foldBTree branch empty tree = ???
```

Looking at the `data` declaration, we know `BTree` has two possible constructors.  We can split the definition into a case for each, and fill out variables for their elements:

```
foldBTree :: (a -> r -> r -> r) -> r -> BTree a -> r
foldBTree branch empty Empty = ???
foldBTree branch empty (Branch a l r) = ???
    -- Let's use comments to keep track of the types:
    -- a :: a
    -- l, r :: BTree a
```

Now, short of something like `undefined`, the only way to fill in the first equation is with `empty`:

```
foldBTree :: (a -> r -> r -> r) -> r -> BTree a -> r
foldBTree branch empty Empty = empty
foldBTree branch empty (Branch a l r) = ???
    -- a :: a
    -- l, r :: BTree a
```

How do we fill in the second equation?  Again, short of `undefined`, we have this:

```
branch :: a -> r -> r -> r
a      :: a
l, r   :: BTree a
```

If we had `subfold :: BTree a -> r`, we could do `branch a (subfold l) (subfold r) :: r`.  But of course, we can write 'subfold' easily:

```
foldBTree :: (a -> r -> r -> r) -> r -> BTree a -> r
foldBTree branch empty Empty = empty
foldBTree branch empty (Branch a l r) = branch a (subfold l) (subfold r)
    where subfold = foldBTree branch empty
```

This is the fold for `BTree`, because `foldBTree Branch Empty anyTree == anyTree`.  Note that `foldBTree` isn't the only function of this type; there's also this:

```
mangleBTree :: (a -> r -> r -> r) -> r -> BTree a -> r
mangleBTree branch empty Empty = empty
mangleBTree branch empty (Branch a l r) = branch a (submangle r) (submangle l)
    where submangle = mangleBTree branch empty
```

But in general, `mangleBTree` doesn't have the required property; for example if we have `foo = Branch 1 (Branch 2 Empty Empty) Empty`, it follows that `mangleBTree Branch Empty foo /= foo`.  So `mangleBTree`, though it has the correct type, is not the fold.

---

Now, let's take a step back from details, and concentrate on that last point with the `mangleTree` example.  A fold (in the structural sense, #2 at the top of my answer) is nothing more and nothing else than the simplest, non-trivial function for an algebraic type such that, when you give pass in the type's constructors as its arguments, it becomes the identity function for that type.  (By nontrivial I mean that things like `foo f z xs = xs` is not allowed.)

This is very significant.  Two ways I like to think about it are as follows:

1. The fold for a given type can "see" all the information contained by any value of that type.  (This is why it's able to perfectly "reconstruct" any value of that type from the ground up using the type's constructors.)
2. The fold is the most general "consumer" function for that type.  Any function that consumes a value of the type in question can be written so that the only operations it uses from that type are the fold and the constructors.  (Though the fold-only versions of some functions are hard to write and perform badly; try writing `tail :: [a] -> [a]` with `foldr`, `(:)` and `[]` as a painful exercise.)

And the second point goes even further, in that you don't even need the constructors.  You can implement any algebraic type without using `data` declarations or constructors, using nothing but folds:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

-- | A Church-encoded list is a function that takes the two 'foldr' arguments
-- and produces a result from them.
newtype ChurchList a = 
    ChurchList { runList :: forall r. 
                            (a -> r -> r)  -- ^ first arg of 'foldr'
                         -> r              -- ^ second arg of 'foldr'
                         -> r              -- ^ 'foldr' result
               }

-- | Convenience function: make a ChurchList out of a regular list
toChurchList :: [a] -> ChurchList a
toChurchList xs = ChurchList (\kons knil -> foldr kons knil xs)

-- | 'toChurchList' isn't actually needed, however, we can make do without '[]'
-- completely.
cons :: a -> ChurchList a -> ChurchList a
cons x xs = ChurchList (\f z -> f x (runlist xs f z))

nil :: ChurchList a
nil = ChurchList (\f z -> z)

foldr' :: (a -> r -> r) -> r -> ChurchList a -> r
foldr' f z xs = runList xs f z

head :: ChurchList a -> Maybe a
head = foldr' ((Just .) . const) Nothing

append :: ChurchList a -> ChurchList a -> ChurchList a
append xs ys = foldr' cons ys xs

-- | Convert a 'ChurchList' to a regular list.
fromChurchList :: ChurchList a -> [a]
fromChurchList xs = runList xs (:) []
```

As an exercise you can try writing other types in this way (which uses the `RankNTypes` extension—[read this for a primer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031878/what-is-the-purpose-of-rank2types/12033549#12033549)).  This technique is called [Church encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding), and is sometimes useful in actual programming—for example, GHC uses something called `foldr`/`build` fusion to optimize list code to remove intermediate lists; see [this Haskell Wiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion), and note the type of `build`:

```
build :: (forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b) -> [a]
build g = g (:) []
```

Except for the `newtype`, this is the same as my `fromChurchList` above.  Basically,  one of the rules that GHC uses to optimize list processing code is this:

```
-- Don't materialize the list if all we're going to do with it is
-- fold it right away:
foldr kons knil (fromChurchList xs) ==> runChurchList xs kons knil
```

By implementing the basic list functions to use Church encodings internally, inlining their definitions aggressively, and applying this rule to the inlined code, nested uses of functions like `map` can be fused into a tight loop.

Comment: Many interesting answers here, but this one comes closest to addressing the question that I actually asked (namely terminology).

Comment: ⁺¹ for the actual application of church encoding. Just recently I was trying to justify its learning, and my findings led to conclusion it's a useless abstraction used for some very special proofs in CS. Now I see it isn't.

Comment: In these examples there's never a constructor with a non-polymorphic component, i.e, `data BTreeWithId a = Empty | Node a (BTreeWithId a) (BTreeWithId a) Int`. It'd be nice to have an example with that.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD according to Gabriel Gonzalez's answer, it should be `foldBTreeWithId :: b -> (a -> b -> b -> Int -> b) -> BTreeWithId a -> b`.

Answer (score 65):

## A Fold for Every Occasion

We can actually come up with a generic notion of folding which can apply to a whole bunch of different types. That is, we can systematically define a `fold` function for lists, trees and more.

This generic notion of `fold` corresponds to the catamorphisms @pelotom mentioned in his comment.

### Recursive Types

The key insight is that these `fold` functions are defined over *recursive* types. In particular:

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a
```

Both of these types are clearly recursive--`List` in the `Cons` case and `Tree` in the `Branch` case.

#### Fixed Points

Just like functions, we can rewrite these types using fixed points. Remember the definition of `fix`:

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

We can actually write something very similar for types, except that it has to have an extra constructor wrapper:

```
newtype Fix f = Roll (f (Fix f))
```

Just like `fix` defines the fixed point of a *function*, this defines the fixed point of a *functor*. We can express all our recursive types using this new `Fix` type.

This allows us to rewrite `List` types as follows:

```
data ListContainer a rest = Cons a rest | Nil
type List a = Fix (ListContainer a)
```

Essentially, `Fix` allows us to nest `ListContainer`s to arbitrary depths. So we could have:

```
Roll Nil
Roll (Cons 1 (Roll Nil))
Roll (Cons 1 (Roll (Cons 2 (Roll Nil))))
```

which correspond to `[]`, `[1]` and `[1,2]` respectively.

Seeing that `ListContainer` is a `Functor` is easy:

```
instance Functor (ListContainer a) where
  fmap f (Cons a rest) = Cons a (f rest)
  fmap f Nil           = Nil
```

I think the mapping from `ListContainer` to `List` is pretty natural: instead of recursing explicitly, we make the recursive part a variable. Then we just use `Fix` to fill that variable in as appropriate.

We can write an analogous type for `Tree` as well.

#### "Unwrapping" Fixed Points

So why do we care? We can define `fold` for *arbitrary* types written using `Fix`. In particular:

```
fold :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> (Fix f -> a)
fold h = h . fmap (fold h) . unRoll
  where unRoll (Roll a) = a
```

Essentially, all a fold does is unwrap the "rolled" type one layer at a time, applying a function to the result each time. This "unrolling" lets us define a fold for any recursive type and neatly and naturally generalize the concept.

For the list example, it works like this:

1. At each step, we unwrap the `Roll` to get either a `Cons` or a `Nil`
2. We recurse over the rest of the list using `fmap`.

   1. In the `Nil` case, `fmap (fold h) Nil = Nil`, so we just return `Nil`.
   2. In the `Cons` case, the `fmap` just continues the fold over the rest of the list.
3. In the end, we get a bunch of nested calls to `fold` ending in a `Nil`--just like the standard `foldr`.

#### Comparing Types

Now lets look at the types of the two fold functions. First, `foldr`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Now, `fold` specialized to `ListContainer`:

```
fold :: (ListContainer a b -> b) -> (Fix (ListContainer a) -> b)
```

At first, these look completely different. However, with a bit of massaging, we can show they're the same. The first two arguments to `foldr` are `a -> b -> b` and `b`. We have a function and a constant. We can think of `b` as `() -> b`. Now we have two functions `_ -> b` where `_` is `()` and `a -> b`. To make life simpler, let's curry the second function giving us `(a, b) -> b`. Now we can write them as a *single* function using `Either`:

```
Either (a, b) () -> b
```

This is true because given `f :: a -> c` and `g :: b -> c`, we can always write the following:

```
h :: Either a b -> c
h (Left a) = f a
h (Right b) = g b
```

So now we can view `foldr` as:

```
foldr :: (Either (a, b) () -> b) -> ([a] -> b)
```

(We are always free to add parentheses around `->` like this as long as they're right-associative.)

Now lets look at `ListContainer`. This type has two cases: `Nil`, which carries no information and `Cons`, which has both an `a` and a `b`. Put another way, `Nil` is like `()` and `Cons` is like `(a, b)`, so we can write:

```
type ListContainer a rest = Either (a, rest) ()
```

Clearly this is the same as what I used in `foldr` above. So now we have:

```
foldr :: (Either (a, b) () -> b) -> ([a] -> b)
fold  :: (Either (a, b) () -> b) -> (List a -> b)
```

So, in fact, the types are isomorphic--just different ways of writing the same thing! I think that's pretty cool.

(As a side note, if you want to know more about this sort of reasoning with types, check out [The Algebra of Algebraic Data Types](https://web.archive.org/web/20180306210122/https://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/), a nice series of blog posts about just this.)

#### Back to Trees

So, we've seen how we can define a generic `fold` for types written as fixed points. We've also seen how this corresponds directly to `foldr` for lists. Now lets look at your second example, the binary tree. We have the type:

```
data Tree a = Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a
```

we can rewrite this using `Fix` by following the rules I did above: we replace the recursive part with a type variable:

```
data TreeContainer a rest = Branch rest rest | Leaf a
type Tree a = Fix (TreeContainer a)
```

Now we have a tree `fold`:

```
fold :: (TreeContainer a b -> b) -> (Tree a -> b)
```

Your original `foldTree` looks like this:

```
foldTree :: (b -> b -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Tree a -> b
```

`foldTree` accepts two functions; we'll combine the into one by first currying and then using `Either`:

```
foldTree :: (Either (b, b) a -> b) -> (Tree a -> b)
```

We can also see how `Either (b, b) a` is isomorphic to `TreeContainer a b`. Tree container has two cases: `Branch`, containing two `b`s and `Leaf`, containing one `a`.

So these fold types are isomorphic in the same way as the list example.

#### Generalizing

There is a clear pattern emerging. Given a normal recursive data type, we can systematically create a non-recursive version of the  type, which lets us express the type as a fixed point of a functor. This means that we can mechanically come up with `fold` functions for all these different types--in fact, we could probably automate the entire process using GHC Generics or something like that.

In a sense, this means that we do not really have different `fold` functions for different types. Rather, we have a single `fold` function which is *very* polymorphic.

### More

I first fully understood these ideas from [a talk](http://conal.net/talks/folds-and-unfolds.pdf) given by Conal Elliott. This goes into more detail and also talks about `unfold`, which is the dual to `fold`.

If you want to delve into this sort of thing even *more* deeply, read the fantastic ["Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire" paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/emeijer/Papers/fpca91.pdf). Among other things, this introduces the notions of "catamorphisms" and "anamorphisms" which correspond to folds and unfolds.

#### Algebras (and Coalgebras)

Also, I can't resist adding a plug for myself :P. You can see some interesting similarities between the way we use `Either` here and the way I used it when talking about [algebras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015020/what-does-coalgebra-mean-in-the-context-of-programming/16022059#16022059) in another SO answer.

There is in fact a deep connection between `fold` and algebras; moreover, `unfold`--the aforementioned dual of `fold`--is connected to coalgebras, which are the dual of algebras. The important idea is that algebraic data types correspond to "initial algebras" which also define folds as outlined in the rest of my answer.

You can see this connection in the general type of `fold`:

```
fold :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> (Fix f -> a)
```

The `f a -> a` term looks very familiar! Remember that an f-algebra was defined as something like:

```
class Functor f => Algebra f a where
  op :: f a -> a
```

So we can think of `fold` as just:

```
fold :: Algebra f a => Fix f -> a
```

Essentially, `fold` just lets us "summarize" structures defined using the algebra.

Comment: After reading this about 8 times, I realized that `ListContainer a b` and `type ListContainer a rest` are NOT used as lists, but as a pair `("head of list", "folded rest of list")`, aka `fmap f (Cons "head of list" "rest of list")` aka `Cons "head of list" (f "rest of list")`, where `f` is `fold h`, which is of course exactly what you wrote.

Answer (score 39):

A fold replaces every constructor with a function.

For example, `foldr cons nil` replaces every `(:)` with `cons` and `[]` with `nil`:

```
foldr cons nil ((:) 1 ((:) 2 [])) = cons 1 (cons 2 nil)
```

For a tree, `foldTree branch leaf` replaces every `Branch` with `branch` and every `Leaf` with `leaf`:

```
foldTree branch leaf (Branch (Branch (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 3))
    = branch (branch (leaf 1) (leaf 2)) (leaf 2)
```

This is why every fold accepts arguments that have the exact same type as the constructors:

```
foldr :: (a -> list -> list) -> list -> [a] -> list

foldTree :: (tree -> tree -> tree) -> (a -> tree) -> Tree a -> tree
```

Comment: is it possible, in this way, to talk about preventing the "mangling" issue mentioned in Luis Casillas's answer?

Comment: There's a really easy way to prove that you're not mangling the tree.  Just pass the original constructors to the fold and prove that you get the same tree back.  Using lists as an example: `foldr (:) [] l = l`.  Using trees as an example `foldTree Branch Leaf t = t`.  The mangling example Luis gave does not return the same tree back if you pass the constructors as arguments.

Answer (score 7):

I would call this a fold, and declare `Tree` a [`Foldable`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldable_and_Traversable#Foldable). See the [`Foldable` example in the GHC docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable).

Comment: Although using `Monoid`s instead of a proper `Tree`-algebra is less than ideal.