# What are the properties of the unsided fold?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, fold

Foldl and folr are 2 very important functions for FP and Haskell, but I have never heard much about the unsided fold:

```
fold f [a,b,c,d] = (f (f a b) (f c d))
```

That is, a fold that operates on binary associative functions (so the order of application doesn't matter). If I recall correctly, this is very common in databases as it can be parallelized. So, about it, I ask:

1. Is it, like foldr, universal?
2. Like foldr, can you define every important function using it?
3. Is there a fusion rule for it, similar to those for foldr/build and unfoldr/destroy?
4. Why is it barely mentioned?
5. Any consideration worth mentioning?

Comment: Probably better-suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com...

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but then realized I wasn't entirely sure what I was talking about. If you're not already aware of it, look at [the `Foldable` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable). It defines a `fold` operation like the one you describe, only with an implicit `f` of `mappend`.

Comment: Please post anyway :/

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426463/what-constitutes-a-fold-for-types-other-than-list/16426964; it goes on about how to define a general fold for any data type.

Comment: I think Clojure "reducers" are relevant here, since Clojure promotes parallel (multicore) reduction of finite seauences (array-style sequences, not cons/linked list)

Answer (score 5):

This is often thought of as tree reduction and is important in parallel computation since it embodies divide and conquer reduction.

First, if the combining function is non-associative then obviously there are big differences between `foldl`, `foldr`, and "unsided fold", so let's assume that we combine with an associative operation. Immediately, all folds can be represented by a `Monoid`.

```
foldlm :: Monoid m => [m] -> m
foldlm = foldl mappend mempty

foldrm :: Monoid m => [m] -> m
foldrm = foldr mappend mempty

usfoldm :: Monoid m => [m] -> m
usfoldm = foldTree mappend mempty . buildTree
```

Which is better represented by `foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> [a] -> m` which is defined by default using `foldr`.

```
foldMap f = foldr (mappend . f) mempty
```

Which is sufficient, if given a final extraction step, to produce tree-like unsided folding given a `Monoid` defined on a tree-like sequence type that controls how the element-`Monoid`s are combined.

```
data Tree a
singleton :: a -> Tree a
instance Monoid (Tree a) where ...
foldTree :: Monoid a => Tree a -> a

foldTree . foldMap singleton :: Monoid a => [a] -> a
```

Finally, we've seen that we can get `foldMap` from `foldr`, but we can also get `foldr` from `foldMap`

```
newtype Endo a = Endo { appEndo :: a -> a }

instance Monoid (Endo a) where
  mempty = id
  mappend (Endo f) (Endo g) = Endo (f . g)

foldr f z as = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) as) z
```

Generally, `foldMap` is considered to be more primitive since it lets the underlying `Monoid` choose its preferred folding method. This means that we're free to write more efficient or more parallel folds on a per-datatype level, though it can still be challenging to do so properly.

It's worth noting that the `foldMap` abstraction is usually found as a instance method of `Foldable` which is a very popular, but more new Haskell typeclass. It's also considered to be a little bit silly despite its practical usefulness because `Foldable` has very few meaningful laws excepting that

```
toList :: Foldable f => f a -> [a]
```

exists, which also lets us see the `Monoid`al nature of `foldMap` as `[a]` is the universal `Monoid` which we can recover with `foldr`.

For further investigation of fusion rules, it would be valuable to read about a proposed dual typeclass `Buildable` as in Gershom Bazerman's [*Building up to a Point via Adjunctions*](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/gbaz/building-up-to-a-point-via-adjunctions).

And finally, as for popularity, I think it's definitely the preferred method of instantiating `Foldable` these days since it allows for more efficient `Monoid` folds if necessary, but it's definitely newer than both `foldl` and `foldr` which likely plays into its relative obscurity.

Comment: That was an awesome post, thank you. Do you have comments on a possible fusion law?

Comment: Without thinking it through entirely, `foldMap f . map g == foldMap (f . g)` seems natural. There is also a build/foldMap fusion possible using Gershom's Buildable class.

Comment: Am I right that given a Monoid and a finite sequence, `foldr` and `foldl` have the same semantics, but different performance characteristics? `Endo` lifts any right fold into a Monoid. What is the left-fold equivalent? `Endo . flip`?

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is `Data.Foldable.foldMap`.

```
foldMap :: Data.Monoid.Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

This function is isomorphic to `foldr`.  As a proof, note that one of `foldMap` or `foldr` is a minimal complete definition of `Foldable`, meaning that each can be written in terms of the other.  That answers your first two questions affirmatively.

I don't know of fusion rules for `foldMap` specifically, but I'm sure that one could exist.  At the very least, foldr fusion rules should apply to some extent.

I have no idea why it's barely mentioned.

One consideration worth mentioning is that, as far as lists are concerned, you can't always take full advantage of this fold.  Since lists are constructed out of cons cells, doing a tree fold would mean traversing half the list, then recursing down each half and traversing half again, etc.  This is a lot of extra traversals compared to `foldl` or `foldr`.  For non-list structures a tree fold can be *much* more efficient, and even for lists it's possible to take some advantage of this.  There was a nice [blog](https://mtnviewmark.wordpress.com/2013/12/02/mfmf/) about one such task recently.

Comment: Enlightening. Thanks.