# What's the practical value of all those newtype wrappers in `Data.Monoid`?

Tags: haskell, monoids

When looking at `Data.Monoid`, I see there are various `newtype` wrappers, such as `All`, `Sum`, or `Product`, which encode various kinds of monoids. However, when trying to use those wrappers, I can't help but wonder what's the benefit over using their non-`Data.Monoid` counterparts. For instance, compare the rather cumbersome summation

```
print $ getSum $ mconcat [ Sum 33, Sum 2, Sum 55 ]
```

vs. the more succinct idiomatic variant

```
print $ sum [ 33, 2, 55 ]
```

But what's the point? Is there any practical value having all those `newtype` wrappers? Are there more convincing examples of `Monoid` `newtype` wrapper usage than the one above?

Comment: I can't say I ever use them.

Comment: `sum = getSum . Data.Foldable.foldMap Sum`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Monoid newtypes: A zero space no-op to tell the compiler what to do

Monoids are great to wrap an existing data type in a new type to tell the compiler what operation you want to do.

Since they're newtypes, they don't take any additional space and applying `Sum` or `getSum` is a no-op.

## Example: Monoids in Foldable

There's more than one way to generalise foldr (see [this very good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426463/what-constitutes-a-fold-for-types-other-than-list) for the most general fold, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22021960/1598537) if you like the tree examples below but want to see a most general fold for trees).

One useful way (not the most general way, but definitely useful) is to say something's foldable if you can combine its elements into one with a binary operation and a start/identity element. That's the point of the `Foldable` typeclass.

Instead of explicitly passing in a binary operation and start element, `Foldable` just asks that the element data type is an instance of Monoid.

At first sight this seems frustrating because we can only use one binary operation per data type - but should we use `(+)` and `0` for `Int` and take sums but never products, or the other way round? Perhaps should we use `((+),0)` for `Int` and `(*),1` for `Integer` and convert when we want the other operation? Wouldn't that waste a lot of precious processor cycles?

### Monoids to the rescue

All we need to do is tag with `Sum` if we want to add, tag with `Product` if we want to multiply, or even tag with a hand-rolled newtype if we want to do something different.

Let's fold some trees! We'll need

```
fold :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => t m -> m    
   -- if the element type is already a monoid
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
   -- if you need to map a function onto the elements first
```

The `DeriveFunctor` and `DeriveFoldable` extensions (`{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable #-}`) are great if you want to map over and fold up your own ADT without writing the tedious instances yourself.

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Tree
import Data.Tree.Pretty -- from the pretty-tree package

see :: Show a => Tree a -> IO ()
see = putStrLn.drawVerticalTree.fmap show

numTree :: Num a => Tree a
numTree = Node 3 [Node 2 [],Node 5 [Node 2 [],Node 1 []],Node 10 []]

familyTree = Node " Grandmama " [Node " Uncle Fester " [Node " Cousin It " []],
                               Node " Gomez - Morticia " [Node " Wednesday " [],
                                                        Node " Pugsley " []]]
```

### Example usage

Strings are already a monoid using `(++)` and `[]`, so we can `fold` with them, but numbers aren't, so we'll tag them using `foldMap`.

```
ghci> see familyTree
               " Grandmama "                
                     |                      
        ----------------------              
       /                      \             
" Uncle Fester "     " Gomez - Morticia "   
       |                      |             
 " Cousin It "           -------------      
                        /             \     
                  " Wednesday "  " Pugsley "
ghci> fold familyTree
" Grandmama  Uncle Fester  Cousin It  Gomez - Morticia  Wednesday  Pugsley "
ghci> see numTree       
     3                  
     |                   
 --------               
/   |    \              
2   5    10             
    |                   
    --                  
   /  \                 
   2  1                 

ghci> getSum $ foldMap Sum numTree
23
ghci> getProduct $ foldMap Product numTree
600
ghci> getAll $ foldMap (All.(<= 10)) numTree
True
ghci> getAny $ foldMap (Any.(> 50)) numTree
False
```

### Roll your own Monoid

But what if we wanted to find the maximum element? We can define our own monoids. I'm not sure why `Max` (and `Min`) aren't in. Maybe it's because no-one likes thinking about `Int` being bounded or they just don't like an identity element that's based on an implementation detail. In any case here it is:

```
newtype Max a = Max {getMax :: a}

instance (Ord a,Bounded a) => Monoid (Max a) where
   mempty = Max minBound
   mappend (Max a) (Max b) = Max $ if a >= b then a else b
```

```
ghci> getMax $ foldMap Max numTree :: Int  -- Int to get Bounded instance
10
```

### Conclusion

We can use newtype Monoid wrappers to tell the compiler which way to combine things in pairs.

The tags do nothing, but show what combining function to use.

It's like passing the functions in as an implicit parameter rather than an explicit one (because that's kind of what a type class does anyway).

Answer (score 9):

How about in an instance like this:

```
myData :: [(Sum Integer, Product Double)]
myData = zip (map Sum [1..100]) (map Product [0.01,0.02..])

main = print $ mconcat myData
```

Or without the newtype wrapper and the `Monoid` instance:

```
myData :: [(Integer, Double)]
myData = zip [1..100] [0.01,0.02..]

main = print $ foldr (\(i, d) (accI, accD) -> (i + accI, d * accD)) (0, 1) myData
```

This is due to the fact that `(Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monoid (a, b)`.  Now, what if you had custom data types and you wanted to fold over a tuple of these values applying a binary operation?  You could simply write a newtype wrapper and make it an instance of `Monoid` with that operation, construct your list of tuples, then just use `mconcat` to fold across them.  There are many other functions that work on `Monoid`s as well, not just `mconcat`, so there are certainly a myriad of applications.

---

You could also look at the `First` and `Last` newtype wrappers for `Maybe a`, I can think of many uses for those.  The `Endo` wrapper is nice if you need to compose a lot of functions, the `Any` and `All` wrappers are good for working with booleans.

Comment: btw, the first example has different output than the 2nd

Comment: @danom Are you sure?  I just copy/pasted it into GHCi and I got the same results.  I didn't unwrap the result for the first example, but that's trivial.

Comment: @danom You might find [this](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/01/haskell-monoids-and-their-uses.html) article helpful as well, it describes, among other things, using `Writer (Sum Integer) Integer` instead of `State Integer Integer` to count the number of steps a computation took, for example.  It explicitly states in the type signature that we _can't_ multiply that value or do anything with it other than add another number to it.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you are working in the `Writer` monad and you want to store the sum of everything you `tell`. In that case you would need the `newtype` wrapper.

You would also need the `newtype` to use functions like `foldMap` that have a `Monoid` constraint.

The `ala` and `alaf` combinators from [`Control.Lens.Wrapped`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.0.4/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html#g:3) in the `lens` package can make working with these newtypes more pleasant. From the documentation:

```
>>> alaf Sum foldMap length ["hello","world"]
10

>>> ala Sum foldMap [1,2,3,4]
10
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you just end up needing a particular `Monoid` to fill a type constraint. One place that shows up sometimes is that `Const` has an `Applicative` instance iff it stores a `Monoid`.

```
instance Monoid m => Applicative (Const m) where
  pure _ = Const mempty
  Const a <*> Const b = Const (a <> b)
```

That's obviously a bit bizarre, but sometimes it's what you need. The best example I know is in `lens` where you end up with types like

```
type Traversal s a = forall f . Applicative f => (a -> f a) -> (s -> f s)
```

If you specialize `f` to something like `Const First` using the `Monoid` newtype `First`

```
newtype First a = First { getFirst :: Maybe a }

-- Retains the first, leftmost 'Just'
instance Monoid (First a) where
  mempty = First Nothing
  mappend (First Nothing)  (First Nothing) = First Nothing
  mappend (First (Just x)) _               = First (Just x)
```

then we can interpret that type

```
(a -> Const (First a) a) -> (s -> Const (First a) s)
```

as scanning through `s` and picking up the first `a` inside of it.

---

So, while that's a really specific answer the broad response is that it's sometimes useful to be able to talk about a bunch of different default `Monoid` behaviors. Somebody had to write all the obvious `Monoid` behaviors, anyway, and they might as well be put in `Data.Monoid`.

Comment: Excellent example; it's not so much bizzare as handy. It's explained as a way of adding logging to an applicative when you're transforming/composing applicatives in the very-worth-reading [Abtracting with Applicatives](http://comonad.com/reader/2012/abstracting-with-applicatives/) from the Comonad Reader.

Comment: Oh, that's a much simpler example. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: `instance Monoid m => Applicative (Const m)` is also a lovely example of an applicative that isn't a monad - there's no `a` to bind to. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: It's one of my two go-to examples of that! The other being the purely-applicative Either.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea, I think, is that you can have something like

```
reduce = foldl (<>) mempty
```

and it'll work for any list of those wrapped things.

Comment: Isn't `reduce` is just `mconcat` implemented with `foldl` instead of `foldr`?