# What are the key differences between Java 8's Optional, Scala's Option and Haskell's Maybe?

Tags: java, scala, haskell

I've read a few posts on Java 8's upcoming Optional type, and I'm trying to understand why people keep suggesting it's not as powerful as Scala's Option. As far as I can tell it has:

- Higher order functions like map and filter using Java 8 lambdas.
- Monadic flatMap
- Short circuiting through getOrElse type functions.

What am I missing?

Comment: "...worse than" - This sounds like a subjective discussion. However, I haven't done anything, yet. Let's see where this goes.

Comment: According to [this post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8s-introduction-optional), they're not going to update all the APIs to use that (such as `List.Get()`). The rest of it can be found [here](http://whyjavasucks.com/).

Comment: Any post which use the word "powerful" is not worth your curiosity.

Comment: Plus, you can still have `null`. The whole point of `Optional`/`Maybe` is that references _can't_ be `null`, so allowing them to be (as Java must, for backwards compatibility) already diminishes some of the benefits.

Comment: @Ankur: I disagree. Power can have a very specific meaning in a context like this (i.e. that you can express some things with one abstraction that are impossible to express with another).

Comment: Since it has flatMap (which is another name for `>>=` in this case. Incidentally, I think "bind" is a better name. "flatMap" really only makes sense for lists), I suspect it is equivalent in power to the Haskell and Scala types. On the other hand, I have a feeling that Haskell's `Maybe` might be easier to use in some cases, for example due to `Applicative`. One issue though is that in Java there is no way to universally quantify over all monads/functors etc which is a more fundamental limitation, but it might make it somewhat less expressive as well (in some sense at least).

Comment: I'd definitely say the type itself is equally powerful as `Maybe`, but it's the language environment that limits each types usability. `Maybe` will get far more use in Haskell/Scala because they're heavily embraced there.

Comment: @yshavit The same applies to Scala.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Except that the Scala standard libraries are largely designed *not* to use null, so idiomatic Scala code only deals with null when Java interop gets involved. Whereas in idiomatic Java once `Optional` arrives... you'll still have to check everything for null explicitly, as most of your values probably come from code that doesn't prefer `Optional` over null.

Comment: @DavidYoung - `bind` doesn't make any sense without training--it may as well be `ulbe` or `tent` or any other random four-letter word.  `flatMap` has the advantage of being quasi-self-explanatory.  Also, in Scala you can do things like `def pruneNulls(xs: List[String]) = xs.flatMap(x => Option(x))`, which doesn't exactly look like a `bind` because of implicit conversion.

Comment: @DavidYoung Actually, I think `flatMap` is a good name for `>>=`, quite apart from lists. It suggests well what `>>=` does for all the monads I can think of at the moment, and I speak as someone who has been around Haskell's monads for a looooong time. Admittedly this conceptual viewpoint could be influenced by my introduction to monads via Wadler's papers.

Comment: @AndrewC Well, it probably depends on your definition of "flatten." To me, it implies that the "layers" are being combined in a way that changes the structure more than just grafting the layers together (in the sense that flattening lists involves more than just "grafting" the layers together). If it is understood in this way, it wouldn't make sense for `Free f` (by definition), `IO`, `Maybe`, `((->) r)`, etc. Since it wouldn't really work for free monads, it seems to not fit the "essence" of "monad" (unless, like I said, you understand "flatten" to mean something else).

Comment: I'd be more okay with something like `joinMap` though.

Comment: @DavidYoung I mean exactly `join` when I say "flatten". I also think flatten is a nice description of the type `Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`. both the type signatures `flatten :: IO (IO a) -> IO a`, `flatten :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a` make perfect sense, and both `flatten :: (r->(r->a)) -> (r->a)` and `flatten :: Functor f => Free f (Free f a) -> Free f a` are at worst as confusing as they are when you say `join` where `flatten` is. `Free f` is a rather special case - its `join` just unwraps slightly, there's no actual joining, and it doesn't really "bind" anyway - it's just a wrapped fmap!

Comment: The free monad is free precisely because it doesn't join but "trees" up - you get your "quotient" monad (to generalise the group theoretic use of free) by replacing the non-bind bind of the free monad with your own bind, a bit like a [generalised tree fold](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426463/what-constitutes-a-fold-for-types-other-than-list).

Comment: @DavidYoung I guess my viewpoint is that people are significantly better (faster, easier, less confusion) when generalising from examples than when instantiating general concepts, so calling it  `flatMap` gives people a way in that calling it bind doesn't. Having said that, I conversely feel that `just` would be a better name than `return`, precisely because `return` comes with too much interpretation baggage for those who use it imperatively.

Comment: Flattening is *exactly* what `join` does to **type** (what "flattening the type" means depends on the monad in question, but it's still a nice general statement you can make about all monads). The name "flatten" also conveys (closer to) the correct intuition for containerish monads like List, whereas "join" sounds like "append". Since bind/flatMap is equivalent to "map and then join", I think there's actually a good argument that we would be best off calling join `flatten` in the programmer's context (much like we call unit `return`), and calling bind `flatMap`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some possibilities come to mind (OTOH, I haven't seen people actually saying that, so they might mean something else):

1. No pattern matching.
2. No equivalent to Scala's `fold` or Haskell's `fromMaybe`: you have to do `optional.map(...).orElseGet(...)` instead.
3. No monadic syntax.

I also wouldn't call any of these "less powerful" myself, since you *can* express everything you can with the corresponding Scala/Haskell types; these are all conciseness/usability concerns.

Comment: "you have to do optional.map(...).orElseGet(...) instead" - and that's not the same thing, because the "else" part gets triggered when either optional is empty or optional.map(...) is empty :)

Answer (score 8):

`Optional` and `Maybe` are effectively in correspondence. Scala has `None` and `Some[A]` as subclassing `Option[A]` which might be more directly comparable to Java since Java could have done the same.

Most other differences either have to do with the ease of handling `Maybe`/`Option` in Haskell/Scala which won't translate since Java is less expressive as a language or the consistency of use of `Maybe`/`Option` in Haskell/Scala where many of the guarantees and conveniences afforded by the type only kick in once most libraries have agreed to use optional types instead of `null`s or exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

For most purposes, they are equivalent; the main difference is that the Scala one is well-integrated into Scala, while the Java one is well-integrated into Java.

The biggest difference in my mind is that Java's is a [value-based class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) That's something new to the JVM. At the moment there's no real difference between value-based and regular classes, but the distinction paves the way for JVM runtimes to eliminate Java object overhead. In other words, a [future JVM](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169) could rewrite Optional code as a directive for how to handle nulls, rather than allocating memory for Optional objects.

Scala does something similar with [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html), though it's done by unboxing types in the compiler rather than in the JVM, and its usage is limited. (Option isn't a value class.)