# What is the most general way to compute the depth of a tree with something like a fold?

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

What minimal (most general) information is required to compute depth of a `Data.Tree`? Is instance of a `Data.Foldable` sufficient?

I initially tried to `fold` a `Tree` and got stuck trying to find right `Monoid` similar to `Max`. Something tells me that since `Monoid` (that would compute depth) needs to be associative, it probably cannot be used to express any fold that needs to be aware of the structure (as in `1 + maxChildrenDepth`), but I'm not certain.

I wonder what thought process would let me arrive at right abstraction for such cases.

Comment: Define what you mean by "minimal information". I think the tree itself is pretty much as simple as it gets, for any "structure with depth".

Comment: I like this question a lot. Perhaps a related question is: is there anything like `Traversable` that uses *both* the `Alternative` and `Applicative` structure of the folding `Functor`?

Comment: (A few more details of what I'm thinking: it wouldn't be hard to define `data Depth a = Depth Nat` with the obvious `Functor` instance. The `Applicative` monoid could be `(+,0)` and the `Alternative` one `(max,0)`.)

Comment: Unfortunately, `Data.Foldable` won't do anything for you here, except provide a (possibly infinite) upper bound. It's just too "one-dimensional". Anything you can do with the `Data.Foldable` instance for `Tree` you can do using just `toList`.

Comment: The minimal information required to compute the depth of a tree is ... the depth of the tree. I know that's not so useful, but it's very clearly true.

Answer (score 5):

I can't say if it's a minimal/most general amount of information. But one general solution is that a given structure

- is a [catamorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism)
- underlying functor of the catamorphism is [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) so that it's possible to enumerate sub-terms.

Here is sample code using [recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Tree

depth :: (Recursive f, Foldable (Base f)) => f -> Int
depth = cata ((+ 1) . maybe 0 getMax . getOption
              . foldMap (Option . Just . Max))

-- Necessary instances for Tree:

data TreeF a t = NodeF { rootLabel' :: a, subForest :: [t] }

type instance Base (Tree a) = TreeF a

instance Functor (TreeF a) where
    fmap f (NodeF x ts) = NodeF x (map f ts)

instance Foldable (TreeF a) where
    foldMap f (NodeF _ ts) = foldMap f ts

instance Recursive (Tree a) where
    project (Node x ts) = NodeF x ts
```

Comment: I don't think that `F.Foldable` instance is law-abiding, since it drops all `rootLabel`s.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. That's a misunderstanding. The data type `TreeF a t` holds 2 kinds of things: The root label of type `a` and the sub-forests of type `t`. The `F.Foldable (TreeF a)` instance iterates on elements of type `t`, that is, on sub-forests - the type `a` is even outside the scope of the instance.

Comment: Four years later and I still don't understand the answer. But yeah, this does look like what I was asking for...

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first question: `Data.Foldable` is **not enough** to compute the depth of the tree. The minimum complete definition of [Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) is `foldr`, which always has the following semantics:

```
foldr f z = Data.List.foldr f z . toList
```

In other words, a `Foldable` instance is *fully* characterized by how it behaves on a list projection of the input (ie `toList`), which will throw away the depth information of a tree.

Other ways of verifying this idea involve the fact that `Foldable` depends on a monoid instance which has to be associative or the fact that the various `fold` functions see the elements one by one in some particular order with no other information, which necessarily throws out the actual tree structure. (There has to be more than one tree with the same set of elements in the same relative order.)

I'm not sure what the minimal abstraction would be for trees *specifically*, but I think the core of your question is actually a bit broader: it would be interesting to see what minimum amount of information is needed to compute arbitrary facts about a type with a fold-like function.

To do this, the actual helper function in the fold would have to take a different sort of argument for each sort of data structure. This naturally leads us to **catamorphisms**, which are generalized folds over different data types.

You can read more about these generalized folds on a different Stack Overflow question: [What constitutes a fold for types other than list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426463/what-constitutes-a-fold-for-types-other-than-list/16426964#16426964) (In the interest of disclosure/self-promotion, I wrote one of the answeres there :P.)