# Haskell Lambda fold

Tags: string, haskell, lambda, fold, algebraic-data-types

I have the following algebraic data type representing the Lambda Calculus in Haskell:

```
data LExpr
    = Var String         -- variable
    | App LExpr LExpr    -- function application
    | Lam String LExpr   -- Lambda abstraction 
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I am trying to build the accompanying fold function. I am acquainted with the general fold form for algebraic data types, which can be in such way present:

```
foldr :: (α -> β-> β) -> β -> [α] -> β
foldr (#) z = go
  where
    go []     = z
    go (x:xs) = x # go xs
```

So, what I have done so far:

```
lfold :: (String -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> (String -> a -> a) -> LExpr -> a   --given by definition
lfold f z = go
  where
    go (Var _) = z            --Not sure here how to do the base case
    go (Lam v e) = v f go e
```

Is this the correct way? If not, where I am wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Take a look at your signature, it is not the same signature as `foldr`, you should name the variables that have changed. Also remember to wrap your constructors in parenthesis. `v f go e` for instance has types `String`, `String -> a`, `LExpr -> a`, and `LExpr` which is a nonsensical call chain.

Comment: @Guvante ok then what corresponds to the signature?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426463/what-constitutes-a-fold-for-types-other-than-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only provide a hint.

Suppose you have a list of integers type as follows:

```
data List = Nil | Cons Int List
```

Then, the fold becomes

```
foldr :: β -> (α -> β -> β) -> [α] -> β
foldr nil cons = go
  where
    go Nil         = nil
    go (Cons x xs) = cons x (go xs)
```

Notice that, once I carefully name the arguments `nil, cons` then it's just a matter of 1) mapping `Nil` (constructor) to `nil` (parameter), 2) mapping `Cons` to `cons`, 3) applying `go` to subterms of type `List` (i.e., `xs`).

For your type,

```
data LExpr
    = Var String         -- variable
    | App LExpr LExpr    -- function application
    | Lam String LExpr   -- Lambda abstraction
```

we can use the same trick:

```
lfold :: (String -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> (String -> a -> a) -> LExpr -> a   
lfold var app lam = go
  where
    go (Var v)     = ??
    go (App e1 e2) = ??
    go (Lam v e)   = ??
```

Notice how I named the three arguments: `var, app, lam`. By checking what happened in the `List` type above, you should now be able to fill in the blanks.

Comment: `go (Var v)     = v`, `go (App e1 e2) = go e1 ++ go e2` and `go (Lam v e)   = v app go e` ? Am I right? And thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @user4325010 No, recall we mapped `Nil` to `nil` and `Cons` to `cons`. So `Var` must be mapped to ... In particular `Var v` must be mapped to `... v`.

Comment: `go (Var v)  = var v`, `go (App e1 e2) = app (go e1) (go e2)`, `go (Lam v e)   = lam v (go e)`? right?

Comment: @user4325010 Perfect!