# logical expression evaluator Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote the following logical expression evaluator. It works for simple 2-member expressions, and it runs but produces a fault for expression containing other expressions as the second/first member. Here's my code.

```
data Expression = Literal Bool | Operation Operator Expression Expression
data Operator = AND | OR

eval :: Expression -> Bool
eval (Literal x)                    = x
eval (Operation AND (Literal x) (Literal y))
 | x == True && y == True           = True
 | otherwise                        = False
eval (Operation OR (Literal x) (Literal y))
 | x == False && y == False         = False
 | otherwise                        = True
```

It works correctly when called with this input:

```
main = do
print $ eval (Operation OR (Literal False) (Literal False))
```

But produces an error when called with this input:

```
main = do
print $ eval( Operation OR (Literal True) (Operation AND (Literal True) (Literal False)) )
```

Comment: You should state the "fault" in the question. One problem that immediately jumps out a "pattern match failed" for the case of nested expressions such as `(Operation OR (Operation AND (Lit True) (Lit False)) (Lit False))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making `eval` a bit too low-level. By including `Literal`s in the signature. A better way to do this is, is using recursion:

```
eval :: Expression -> Bool
eval (Literal x) = x
eval (Operation AND x y) = (eval x) && (eval y)
eval (Operation OR x y) = (eval x) || (eval y)
```

In other words call `eval` on the *right-hand-side*. In case it is a `Literal`, it will immediately resolve to the correct value, in case it is a cascaded expression, it will resolve that `Operation _ _ _` as well.

In general it is not advisable to start cascaded pattern matching (ok, sometimes it is useful). In that case you should at least ask yourself if there is no more elegant solution.

This piece of code easily shows that the function is *total* (regardless of the input, it will always generate a result). That's not the case for your code. Always try to perform a *totality-check*.

## Edit

In case the number of `Operation`s will increase significantly, you better separate concerns into a `handler :: Operation -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool` function and the `eval` function. Something like:

```
data Expression = Literal Bool | Operation Operator Expression Expression
data Operator = AND | OR | XOR

handler :: Operation -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool
handler AND = (&&)
handler OR = (||)
handler XOR = xor
    where xor True False = True
          xor False True = True
          xor _ _ = False

eval :: Expression -> Bool
eval (Literal x) = x
eval (Operation o x y) = (handler o) (eval x) (eval y)
```

---

In case you need to handle a `NOT`, that's another type of expression:

```
data Expression = Literal Bool | Operation Operator Expression Expression | OperationU OperatorU Expression
```

`OperatorU` is here an unary operator. For instance:

```
data OperatorU = ID | NOT
```

with `ID` the identity. Now in that case you can define a second handler:

```
handlerU :: OperatorU -> Bool -> Bool
handlerU ID = id
handlerU NOT = not
```

and then `eval` reads:

```
eval :: Expression -> Bool
eval (Literal x) = x
eval (Operation o x y) = (handler o) (eval x) (eval y)
eval (OperationU o x) = (handlerU o) (eval x)
```

Comment: but what if I also needed to be able to handle NOT which only takes 1 argument?

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer by CommuSoft.  I'm going to riff on that and go a bit more high-level/philosophical.

One key guideline to follow in designing languages and interpreters for them is the [principle of compositionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality):

- The meaning of a complex expression should be a function of the meaning of its parts and their manner of combination.

In this case, the "meanings" are the `Bool`s that the expressions evaluate to.  Applied to your evaluator, what compositionality means is:

- Your evaluator should only look at the *meanings* (`Bool` evaluation results) of subexpressions, never their *syntax*.

This equation of your `eval` violates that rule, because it "peeks" inside the subexpressions to examine whether the `Literal` constructor is there:

```
eval (Operation AND (Literal x) (Literal y))
 | x == True && y == True           = True
 | otherwise                        = False
```

One useful trick to make sure you're doing things compositionally is this:

1. Write a generic fold function over the syntax tree type.  (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426463/what-constitutes-a-fold-for-types-other-than-list) for some guidance on this concept.)
2. Write your evaluator in terms of that fold function.

In this case:

```
data Expression = Literal Bool | Operation Operator Expression Expression
data Operator = AND | OR

foldExpression :: (Bool -> r) -> (Operator -> r -> r -> r) -> r
foldExpression f _ (Literal x) = f x
foldExpression f g (Operation op l r) = g op (subfold l) (subfold r)
    where subfold = foldExpression f g
```

The trick is that when you use `foldExpression` it prevents you from seeing the constructors of nodes below the current expression, so you are forced to work in in terms of the result type `r`.  So here goes:

```
eval :: Expression -> Bool
eval = foldExpression evalLiteral evalOperation
    where 
      -- A literal just evals to the `Bool` it carries.
      evalLiteral :: Bool -> Bool
      evalLiteral b = b

      evalOperation :: Operator -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool

      -- An `AND` operation evaluates to the `&&` of its subexpressions' values
      evalOperation (AND l r) = l && r

      -- An `OR` operation evaluates to the `||` of its subexpressions' values
      evalOperation (OR l r) = l || r
```

And note how `evalOperation` is the same thing as CommuSoft's `handler` function.  This just fell out naturally from writing  the solution as a fold.

---

A bit more worked out, including unary operations and understandability-at-scale:

```
data Unary = Not
data Binary = And | Or | If
data Expr = Lit Bool | Expr1 Unary Expr | Expr2 Binary Expr Expr

-- Package all the functions used in a fold into a record
-- so that we don't need to remember the argument order.
-- For complex tree types with many types of nodes you will 
-- want this!
data ExprFold r 
    = ExprFold { literal :: Bool -> r
               , unary :: Unary -> r -> r
               , binary :: Binary -> r -> r -> r
               }

foldExpr :: ExprFold r -> Expr -> r
foldExpr f (Lit b) = literal f b
foldExpr f (Expr1 e) = unary f (foldExpr f e)
foldExpr f (Expr2 e e') = binary f (foldExpr f e) (foldExpr f e')

evaluator :: ExprFold Bool
evaluator = ExprFold { literal = evalLit
                     , unary = evalExpr1
                     , binary = evalExpr2 }
    where 
      evalLit b = b
      evalExpr1 (Not b) = not b
      evalExpr2 (And b b') = b && b'
      evalExpr2 (Or b b') = b || b'
      evalExpr2 (If b b') = not b || b'
```